# Change Active Directory / Domain Controller in Ms CRM

Tags: active-directory, dynamics-crm, domaincontroller

We have had a working MS CRM 2016 up until now, some thing happened and we lost our Domain Controller and Active Directory Machine, now we can not even login to ms crm, or even open the Deployment Manager since no user from that AD is available any more, is there any way to change the AD settings in MS CRM or anyother way to not reinstall the MS CRM ?

Basically the question would be this,

How to change a working MS CRM's Domain and AD to a new Domain (Even with same name) while the current AD is not accessible.

Comment: please try posting here: https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/active-directory

Comment: it's more of a Dynamics Crm question rather than AD ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Appearently this is not possible, at least in a supported way.

The supported way is

1- install a fresh CRM in a computer in the new domain

2- remove the fresh organization from Deployment Manager

3- restore the previous database in the sql server your going to use with your new CRM (obviously should be in the new domain)

4- from Deployment Manager, Organization section, Import an organization, connect to the restored database and related sql reporting server in the wizard, and select automatic user mapping (in this part users get mapped based on their login name and the users which can not be mapped will be asked from you)

5- Hallelujah